# Discord.py | When bot left, kicked, banned from a server

Tags: python, database, sqlite, discord.py

There is the code that works here it is:

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(curser):
    print(curser.id)
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for server in guild.name:
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM server where id={curser.id}")
            if cursor.fetchone()==None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO server VALUES ({curser.id}, '{curser.name}', 1)")
            else:
                pass
                conn.commit()
```

I need a code like this(below):

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_leave(curser):
    print(curser.id)
    for server in cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM server where id={curser.id}"):
        if cursor.fetchone()!=None:
            cursor.execute(f"UPDATE server SET isExists=(0) WHERE id={curser.id}")
        else:
            pass
            conn.commit()
```

so that, on the contrary, when the bot was kicked or banned or left from a server, the values in the database changed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a **specific question** about your algorithm or technique. If you have no idea where to start, you need to look up a tutorial or talk to a tutor.

Comment: `on_guild_remove` is what you are looking for, And as @Ceres mentioned, we do not implement a feature for you. This site is only for help with code issues.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@bot.event
async def on_guild_leave(guild):
    try:
        cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM server WHERE id={guild.id}")
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    SINGLEQUOTE = "'"
    ESCAPEDSINGLEQUOTE = "\\'"
    try:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO server VALUES ({guild.id}, '{guild.name.replace(SINGLEQUOTE,ESCAPEDSINGLEQUOTE)}', 1)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

If there is a single quote in guild name, it will create error, so you should replace them with `\'`

I think you won't need checking if guild is in the database. Easily you can use try-except.

Comment: Events on_guild_leave, on_guild_remove, on_guild_delete don't work. No responses